# Passing a star to lua

Tags: luatex, arguments, starred-version

I hope this is a simple question, but I could not find documentation on it. Maybe I am searching for the wrong keywords.

I want to pass a star `*` option to my lua code. I believe it is a boolean, based on code from an older project. `\bool_if:NTF #1 {do true stuff}{do false stuff}`

But something about passing a star as a parameter breaks the code.

```
\NewDocumentCommand{\addline}{smm}{\directlua{myluacodefile.addline(#1,"#2","#3")}}%
```

Here is a minimum "working" example

**main.tex**

```
\documentclass[letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage{xparse}%for advanced command declaration

\directlua{myluacodefile = require("myluacodefile")}%this links the .lua
\newcommand{\sanitycheck}[2]{\directlua{myluacodefile.sanitycheck(#1,#2)}}%

%\NewDocumentCommand{\addline}{mm}{\directlua{myluacodefile.addline("A","#1","#2")}}%turn this on to see the code "work"
\NewDocumentCommand{\addline}{smm}{\directlua{myluacodefile.addline(#1,"#2","#3")}}%

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}

hello

\sanitycheck{1}{2}

\addline{first}{second}

\addline*{third}{fourth}

\end{document}
```

**myluacodefile.lua**

```
local myluacodefile = {}--lua module start

name = "Sanity Check"

function myluacodefile.sanitycheck(a,b)
    c=a+b
    tex.print(c)
    tex.print(name)
end


function myluacodefile.addline(star, alpha, beta)
    local testa = alpha
    local testb = beta
    tex.print(testa)
    tex.print(testb)
end

return myluacodefile--lua module end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question right, this maybe works:

### main.tex

`xparse` allows to define both a starred and a unstarred command. As you said, the star implies a boolean, so you have to define commands for the starred and the unstarred forms separately with `\IfBooleanTF#1{true}{false}`. As for the Lua side, you will have to include a third argument.

```
%!TEX program = lualatex
\documentclass[letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage{xparse}%for advanced command declaration

\directlua{myluacodefile = require("myluacodefile")}%this links the .lua
%\NewDocumentCommand{\addline}{mm}{\directlua{myluacodefile.addline("A","#1","#2")}}%turn this on to see the code "work"
\NewDocumentCommand{\addline}{smm}{%
%If you need some code to be executed independently of the star, put it here.
\IfBooleanTF#1{%
\directlua{myluacodefile.addline("star","#2","#3")}
}{\directlua{myluacodefile.addline("nostar","#2","#3")}}
}%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}

hello

\addline{first}{second}

\addline*{third}{fourth}

\end{document}
```

### myluacodefile.lua

In the Lua side, we add an argument to read the star or its absence.

```lua
local myluacodefile = {}--lua module start

name = "Sanity Check"

function myluacodefile.sanitycheck(a,b)
    c=a+b
    tex.print(c)
    tex.print(name)
end


function myluacodefile.addline(star, alpha, beta)
    local warning = "There's no star!"
    local check = "There's a star!"
    local testa = alpha
    local testb = beta
--I put this as an example, but you can define your own macros according to your needs
    if star == "nostar" then 
    --Unstarred
     tex.print(warning) 
    elseif star == "star" then
    --Starred 
     tex.print(check) 
    end
    tex.print(testa)
    tex.print(testb)
end

return myluacodefile--lua module end
```

[image]

Comment: While this does produce a correct output, its is a work around. We havnt actually passed the star parameter. Instead you have written an interpreter layer between the newcommand and lua converting the star into a string. I was more curious of why passing the #1 as an argument broke the lua with its native data type.

Comment: I'm not a frequent LaTeX user, so I don't really know, but maybe the documentation say something about it. What I could read is that the star is considered as an argument whose exact nature I haven't find out. Maybe the implementation of `xparse` says something.

Comment: @Bob It's not a workaround. You're supposed to use the star argument using `\IfBooleanTF{#1}{<star code>}{<nostar code>}`

Comment: The more you know...

Comment: @JairoAraujo Well it is a good solution for the mean time. Thank you.

Comment: @egreg Do you mean to say that you cannot use the #1 argument in any other way? Using an if statement to write a `{star code}` and `{no star code}` makes me think it should be able to be passed like any other argument. Is it special in some way?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that in past implementation of `xparse` the code for an `s`-argument was passed via a conditional. But one should never rely on the details of the implementation.

The “official” way to use an `s`-argument is via

```
\IfBooleanTF{#1}{<code for star>}{<code for nostar>}
```

or via `\bool_if:nTF` if passed to the `expl3` level. Definitely not with `\bool_if:NTF`.

With your code, the Lua function is passed either `\BooleanTrue` or `\BooleanFalse`, and this makes no sense to Lua. Actually you can easily discover that `\BooleanTrue` and `\BooleanFalse` are `\chardef` tokens with value 1 and 0 respectively, but these are implementation details that should *never* be relied upon.

You can do

```latex
\NewDocumentCommand{\addline}{smm}{%
  \directlua{myluacodefile.addline("\IfBooleanTF{#1}{star}{nostar}","#2","#3")}%
}
```

because the construct `\IfBooleanTF` is fully expandable.

Comment: @MarcelKrüger You're the Lua expert. I'll add the quotes; `star` and `nostar` stand for anything meaningful in the context.

Comment: @MarcelKrüger could you elaborate on the passing of a lua boolean? That seem like a cleaner solution to a string interpreter.

Comment: @Bob I guess he meant `\IfBooleanTF{#1}{true}{false}` (without quotes).

Comment: I want to see something cleaner, too. My Lua knowledge is still rudimentary.

Comment: @JairoAraujo I tested passing just true or false without quotes just as egreg suggested, lua does indeed interpret that correctly as a boolean. So you can do something like `if star then else end` and it works out.